# mysqli update database receiving email and password reset token

Tags: php, forms, session, mysqli

I have searched and searched. I have multiple queries functioning on the website, except for the final two, which are in this file. I just cannot find/figure it out. Exhausting.

I have created a reset password function. The user puts in their email and if that email is found in my database a reset token is sent to that email.  When that reset link in the email is clicked it directs to the reset password page with the email and token information.

Everything is functioning as it should other than the tables not updating. I want to update the idaccount table with the ipaddress and new password. I want to update the resets table with ipaddress and "UsedToken" in the used column. (This way I can get double use of the table. Shows specific data if user changed password in their account logged in and emails/tokens requested.) Ultimately I want to craft code that a token cannot be reused based on the "used" column not empty and verifies that the token was in fact used.

Basic HTML Form to change password:

```
<body>


<form id="forgotpwdreset" name="forgotpwdreset" method="post" action="" onsubmit="forgotpwdalert()"<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>

<table border="0">
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>

    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />


    Password must be at least 8 characters long and contain at least 1 number AND 1 capital letter.<br /><br />
    <tr>New Password:  <align="center"><input required type="password" name="newpassword" id="newpassword" placeholder="" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" onclick="togglepassword()"> Show Password<br /><br />
    <tr></tr><br />

    <tr>Confirm Password:  <align="center"><input required type="password" name="newpassword2" id="newpassword2" placeholder="" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" onchange="confirmpwd()"><br />
    <tr></tr><br />

    <tr>
    <tr></tr><br />

    <tr><align="center"><input type="submit" name="pwdresetsubmit" id="pwdresetsubmit" value="Reset Password" onclick="return confirmpwd()" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
    <tr></tr><br />

    </table>
</form>

</body>
```

PHP to handle the form:

```
    <?php

    include 'insert.php';

    if(isset($_SESSION['ondashsession'])){

    $session = $_SESSION['ondashsession'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ondash_idaccount WHERE ID = '$session'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql) or die("Error");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     echo "You are already logged in,  " . $row['firstname'] . "." . "<br />";
}
}else{



if (isset($_POST['pwdresetsubmit'])) {

  $newpassword2 = $_POST['newpassword2'];
  $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE ADDR'];
  // Grab token and email that came from the email link
  $token = $_GET['token'];
  $email = $_GET['email'];

 //echo "Token:  " . $token . "<br />" . "Email:  " . $email; //returns correct info working properly.


 // select email address of user from the password_reset table 

    $sqlnewpass = "SELECT * FROM password_resets WHERE token='$token' AND email='$email'";
    $results = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlnewpass);


if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0 ){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

//  print_r($row['email']); //returns correct result
//  print_r("# of rows:  " . $numrows);  //returns correct result

//WORKS UP TO HERE...WORKS UP TO HERE...WORKS UP TO HERE...WORKS UP TO HERE...WORKS UP TO HERE...WORKS UP TO HERE...

    $sql2 = "UPDATE ondash_idaccount SET `password`=?, `ipaddress`=? WHERE `email`='$email'";
    $stmt2 = mysqli_stmt_init($dbcon);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt2, $sql2)){
    echo "SQL error" . $dbcon->error;
}else{

    $hashedpassword = password_hash($newpassword2, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    //var_dump($hashedpassword); //generating hash pwd works but not updating database


    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "ss", $hashedpassword, $ipaddress);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
    $stmt2->close();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
//  echo "SQL 2 error" . $dbcon->error; //No errors reporting

    $UsedToken = 'UsedToken';

    "UPDATE password_resets SET `used`='$UsedToken', `ipaddress`='$ipaddress' WHERE `token`='$token' AND `email`='$email'";


}
}
}

?>
```

Neither table is updating. What am I missing? Any help for this newbie would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

The first query was halted due to a typo. I had `$_SERVER['REMOTE ADDR'];`. Notice the _ is missing. Therefore, the whole query halted without errors. Changed to `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` and voila! Finding this was a stinker. Basically, I echoed out each variable with some tag to know what was displaying and noticed the ipaddress was blank!

The second query still not sure what was going on. However, following a great suggestion to bind parameters (which I should have done regardless to be sure) I rewrote the code (one last blasted time!) to do so. Again, voila!

I am posting my updated code. Hope it is useful to someone having trouble with receiving and updating related to password reset token. I have also implemented the strategy that a token cannot be reused. All works like a beast!

Updated PHP:

```
<?php

include 'insert.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['ondashsession'])){

$session = $_SESSION['ondashsession'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ondash_idaccount WHERE ID = '$session'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     echo "You are already logged in,  " . $row['firstname'] . "." . "<br />";
}
}else{

//Check if token has already been used

$token = $_GET['token'];
$email = $_GET['email'];

$sqlused = "SELECT * FROM password_resets WHERE token='$token' AND email='$email'";
$resultsused = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlused);


   if (mysqli_num_rows($resultsused) > 0 ){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsused);
//echo $row['used'];

    if($row['used'] == 'UsedToken'){

        echo "<strong>That reset link has already been used. Please request another.</strong>";

  }else{

if (isset($_POST['pwdresetsubmit'])) {

error_reporting(E_ALL);

  $newpassword2 = $_POST['newpassword2'];
  $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

  // Grab token and email that came from the email link

  $token = $_GET['token'];
  $email = $_GET['email'];

 // select data from password_reset table 

    $sqlnewpass = "SELECT * FROM password_resets WHERE token='$token' AND email='$email'";
    $results = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlnewpass);


   if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0 ){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

//update user password in database

    $sql2 = "UPDATE ondash_idaccount SET `password`=?, `ipaddress`=? WHERE `email`='$email'";
    $stmt2 = mysqli_stmt_init($dbcon);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt2, $sql2)){
    echo "SQL error" . $dbcon->error;
}else{

    $hashedpassword = password_hash($newpassword2, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    //var_dump($hashedpassword); //generating hash pwd works but not updating database


    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "ss", $hashedpassword, $ipaddress);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
    $stmt2->close();

    echo "<strong>Password successfully reset!</strong>";

//Update pwd reset table

$UsedToken = 'UsedToken';

    $sql3 = "UPDATE password_resets SET `used`=?, `ipaddress`=? WHERE `token`='$token' AND `email`='$email'";
    $stmt3 = mysqli_stmt_init($dbcon);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt3, $sql3)){
    echo "SQL error" . $dbcon->error;
}else{

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt3, "ss", $UsedToken, $ipaddress);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt3);
    $stmt3->close();
//  echo "SQL 2 error" . $dbcon->error; //No errors reporting
//  echo $row['email'] . $row['ipaddress'];
```

Comment: "no error" - This isn't proper error handling `or die("Error")`. `mysqli_error($dbcon)` is.

Comment: and why aren't you using a prepared statement throughout?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` will only work if that condition it's in is met. Place that at the top.

Comment: `"UPDATE password_resets SET.....` - Umm... that looks to be incomplete and isn't executed.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: I have changed the error as suggested in both 1 and 3 of your comments. #2 comment... I didn't think I needed to prepare that update as I am supplying the info and the token and email must match. I can change that if needed. #4 Can you explain how it is incomplete? Does programming subscribe to "writer's block?" Because that is where I feel I am at today.

Comment: TBH, there's too much to do here. What I suggest you to do would be to cut down your queries to a bare minimum to see where it starts to break. That way you can find out where and what caused it to fail and by enabling enabling error reporting for the PHP and (proper) error handling on the mysql.

Comment: @FunkyFortyNiner: ok thank you. I have been trying to piece it that's why I have all of the echos commented out as I retrieve info pieces. I will continue.

Comment: I went ahead and bound parameters in second query. Whatever I did in the mix fixed the second query. The first query was fixed by a simple "_". I did not have it in the remote addr to grab the ipaddress which halted the whole query. Thank you for your assistance it got me to the end point!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to see it worked out for you Kristina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The first query was halted due to a typo. I had `$_SERVER['REMOTE ADDR'];`. Notice the _ is missing. Therefore, the whole query halted without errors. Changed to `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` and voila! Finding this was a stinker. Basically, I echoed out each variable with some tag to know what was displaying and noticed the ipaddress was blank!

The second query still not sure what was going on. However, following a great suggestion to bind parameters (which I should have done regardless to be sure) I rewrote the code (one last blasted time!) to do so. Again, voila!

I am posting my updated code. Hope it is useful to someone having trouble with receiving and updating related to password reset token. I have also implemented the strategy that a token cannot be reused. All works like a beast!

Updated PHP:

```
<?php

include 'insert.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['ondashsession'])){

$session = $_SESSION['ondashsession'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ondash_idaccount WHERE ID = '$session'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     echo "You are already logged in,  " . $row['firstname'] . "." . "<br />";
}
}else{

//Check if token has already been used

$token = $_GET['token'];
$email = $_GET['email'];

$sqlused = "SELECT * FROM password_resets WHERE token='$token' AND email='$email'";
$resultsused = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlused);


   if (mysqli_num_rows($resultsused) > 0 ){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsused);
//echo $row['used'];

    if($row['used'] == 'UsedToken'){

        echo "<strong>That reset link has already been used. Please request another.</strong>";

  }else{

if (isset($_POST['pwdresetsubmit'])) {

error_reporting(E_ALL);

  $newpassword2 = $_POST['newpassword2'];
  $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

  // Grab token and email that came from the email link

  $token = $_GET['token'];
  $email = $_GET['email'];

 // select data from password_reset table 

    $sqlnewpass = "SELECT * FROM password_resets WHERE token='$token' AND email='$email'";
    $results = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlnewpass);


   if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0 ){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

//update user password in database

    $sql2 = "UPDATE ondash_idaccount SET `password`=?, `ipaddress`=? WHERE `email`='$email'";
    $stmt2 = mysqli_stmt_init($dbcon);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt2, $sql2)){
    echo "SQL error" . $dbcon->error;
}else{

    $hashedpassword = password_hash($newpassword2, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    //var_dump($hashedpassword); //generating hash pwd works but not updating database


    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "ss", $hashedpassword, $ipaddress);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
    $stmt2->close();

    echo "<strong>Password successfully reset!</strong>";

//Update pwd reset table

$UsedToken = 'UsedToken';

    $sql3 = "UPDATE password_resets SET `used`=?, `ipaddress`=? WHERE `token`='$token' AND `email`='$email'";
    $stmt3 = mysqli_stmt_init($dbcon);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt3, $sql3)){
    echo "SQL error" . $dbcon->error;
}else{

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt3, "ss", $UsedToken, $ipaddress);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt3);
    $stmt3->close();
//  echo "SQL 2 error" . $dbcon->error; //No errors reporting
//  echo $row['email'] . $row['ipaddress'];


}   
}
}
}
}
}
}
}    


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an obvious error in your PHP code.

I ran a simplified version here:

```
$newpassword2 = "TESTME";
$ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";

$token = "my_token";
$email = "email@email.com";

$sqlnewpass = "SELECT * FROM tmp_password_resets WHERE token='$token' AND 
email='$email'";
$results = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlnewpass);


if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0 ){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

    $sql2 = "UPDATE tmp_ondash_idaccount SET `password`=?, `ipaddress`=? WHERE `email`='$email'";
    $stmt2 = mysqli_stmt_init($dbcon);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt2, $sql2)){
    echo "SQL error" . $dbcon->error;
}else{
    $hashedpassword = "MY_HASHED_PASSWORD";

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "ss", $hashedpassword, $ipaddress);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
    $stmt2->close();

    $UsedToken = 'UsedToken';
}
}
```

This ran the UPDATE successfully. I would propose you examine:
* The incoming variables: does the email actually match the row in both tables? Are they the same datatype? Case insensitive?
* The table structure: are the fields the right size and type for the incoming strings?

Also, I notice you're mixing the procedural and OOP style uses of the mysqli prepared statements. Have you considered using the PDO connector instead for consistency? On that same note: there are areas where you're using bindParam but not others (SQL injection!). As far as I see you could actually be using bindValue for all those cases, regardless.

Comment: Hi, Tim. Thank you for your assistance. Your code does work. Yes the incoming variables are exact. Same datatype and not case sensitive. I see I am mixing and that was unintentional. Frustration and inexperience, I guess. I have not considered PDO, at this date. I am barely hanging on with what I have learned in a couple of months. (very new)

Comment: I went ahead and bound parameters in second query. Whatever I did in the mix fixed the second query. The first query was fixed by a simple "_". I did not have it in the remote addr to grab the ipaddress which halted the whole query. Thank you for your assistance it got me to the end point!